# How to convert text datatype of date column to timestamp format when importing from CSV to SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to import a 9 GB CSV file which has date column as a text field.
I wanted to import in MS SQL Server with simple yyyy/mm/dd format. 
But the current format is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'  
Example:

2017-07-01T14:59:55.711'+0000' 
2017-07-01T14:59:55.711Z

Expected after importing the data:
2017-07-01

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562420/how-to-import-csv-with-unrecognized-datetime-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the date/time as text (the default), then change the column type to 'date' afterwards.

Edit; missed a step required to truncate the imported 'thedate' string before changing the column type:

```
update importeddata set thedate=SUBSTRING(thedate,0,24)
```

Comment: What does the number 24 mean?

Comment: It is the length of the string returned (basically cutting off the 'Z' or '+0000'). This leaves the time portion intact, so you could also change to 'datetime. Thinking of it, you could also use LEFT(thedate, 10) to truncate down to the date portion.